# Match closest filename based on timestamp

Tags: shell, unix

We have backups stored in S3 and need to retrieve a backup based on nearest time stamp. We have files stored in S3 in YYYYMMDD_HHMM.tar.gz format

```
20181009_0910.tar.gz
20181004_0719.tar.gz
20180925_0414.tar.gz
20180915_2210.tar.gz
```

Given a timestamp 20180922_1020, we need to fetch file 20180925_0414.tar.gz using shell script.

Thanks.

Comment: is there any limit to how nearer timestamp file you need to fetch? like 2 days, 3days, etc?

Comment: There is no limit. We need to fetch file from given set of files.

Comment: Do you always want to fetch the file that is _after_ the given timestamp, or is "fewest seconds in either direction" the winner?  Also, what have you tried? Given your tags, I'd expect to see at least a little bit of shell code that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl One liner ( Of-course somewhat lengthy !!).

I understand that "nearest" means shortest between the input in either direction. That is if you have 2 files, Oct-1st.txt and Oct-30.txt, and if the input is Oct-20, then Oct-30 file will be the output

```
$ ls -l *2018*gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Oct 17 00:04 20180915_2210.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Oct 17 00:04 20180925_0414.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Oct 17 00:04 20181004_0719.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxx xxxx 0 Oct 17 00:04 20181009_0910.tar.gz

$ export input=20180922_1020

$ perl -ne 'BEGIN { @VAR=@ARGV; $in=$ENV{input}; $in=~s/_//g;foreach(@VAR) {$x=$_;s/.tar.gz//g;s/_//g;s/(\d+)/abs($1-$in)/e;$KV{$_}=$x};$res=(sort keys %KV)[0]; print "$KV{$res}"} ' 2018*gz
20180925_0414.tar.gz

$ export input=20180905_0101

$ perl -ne 'BEGIN { @VAR=@ARGV; $in=$ENV{input}; $in=~s/_//g;foreach(@VAR) {$x=$_;s/.tar.gz//g;s/_//g;s/(\d+)/abs($1-$in)/e;$KV{$_}=$x};$res=(sort keys %KV)[0]; print "$KV{$res}"} ' 2018*gz
20180915_2210.tar.gz

$
```

Hope, this helps!