# Replace a line based upon the file content

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, unix-timestamp

I have a file which contains timestamp and date in the second column. If the line contains one of the word then it need to be replace like below. Any help is appreciated.

```
File:
a smallint
b timestamp
c date
d varchar

O/P:
a smallint
dateformat(b,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss')
dateformat(c.'YYYY-MM-DD')
d varchar
```

If I add awk in a seperate statement then its working but If I add if else statement then I am getting error.

```
awk '{if ($2=="timestamp") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)" else ($2=="date") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)" }' test.out 

Error:
awk: {if ($2=="timestamp") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss)" else ($2=="date") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD)" }
awk: ^ syntax error
awk: {if ($2=="timestamp") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss)" else ($2=="date") {$3="dataformat("; }; print $3 $1 ",'YYYY-MM-DD)" }
awk: ^ syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to indent your code (in `awk` you can use newlines between the single quotes), you will see that you have a `print` before the `else`.

```
   awk '{
      if ($2=="timestamp") {
         $3="dataformat(";
      };
      print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)"
      else
      ($2=="date") {
         $3="dataformat(";
      };
      print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)"
   }' test.out
```

This code can be "fixed" with

```
   awk '{
      if ($2=="timestamp") {
         $3="dataformat(";
         print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD HH'\:'NN'\:'SS'\.'sss)"
      }
      if ($2=="date") {
         $3="dataformat(";
         print $3 $1 ",'\''YYYY-MM-DD)"
      }
   }' test.out
```

You see you do not need an else statement.
Now more issues appear. You shouldn't use `$3` for a variable, just make a new one.
Variables can be set as an awk parameter, in a BEGIN {} section or in the normal flow.
I would use the parameters for the variables with a single quote. I also introduced `startvar` and `othervar`, just for showing how they work.

```
   awk -v ymd="'YYYY-MM-DD'" \
       -v dt="'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss'" \
     '
        BEGIN {
           startvar="Example variable"
        }
        $2=="timestamp" {
            printf("%s, dateformat(%s)\n", $1, ymd);
            othervar=startvar" expanded";
            print othervar;
        }
        $2=="date" {
           printf("%s, dateformat(%s)\n", $1, dt);
        }
      ' test.out
```

Without the demo part with the additional vars, and removing some newlines, you get

```
   awk -v ymd="'YYYY-MM-DD'" -v dt="'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss'" '
        $2=="timestamp" { printf("%s, dateformat(%s)\n", $1, ymd); }
        $2=="date" { printf("%s, dateformat(%s)\n", $1, dt); }
     ' test.out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    fmt["timestamp"] = "dateformat(%s,\047YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss\047)"
    fmt["date"]      = "dateformat(%s.\047YYYY-MM-DD\047)"
}
$2 in fmt { $0 = sprintf(fmt[$2],$1) }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a smallint
dateformat(b,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss')
dateformat(c.'YYYY-MM-DD')
d varchar
```

Since the script is in a file I could have used literal `'`s but I used `\047`s instead so you could use it as `awk 'script' file` instead if you like.

Comment: '@Ed do you have awk solution for this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52839660

Comment: Whatever it is the OP wants to do it'd be trivial but in a week of waiting she still hasn't answered the crucial question @ghoti asked yet nor has she provided any attempt herself and if she can't be bothered following up with her own question, I certainly can't be bothered either.

Comment: '@Ed sorry.. I was trying it in awk for sometime and didn't have luck.

Comment: No problem but I don't know what her criteria for "nearest" is, nor what to do if multiple files are as "near" as each other, nor do I even know if she has files in a directory named S3 or a list of files stored in a file named S3 or something else. There's just not enough information in the question to try to answer it AND she hasn't even provided her own attempt.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to use single or double quotes within awk, use the octal notation. 
\047 - single quotes.
See below

```
> cat datatype.txt
a smallint
b timestamp
c date
d varchar
> awk -F" " ' { if($2~/date/) { print "dateformat("$1".\047YYYY-MM-DD\047)" } } ' datatype.txt
dateformat(c.'YYYY-MM-DD')
> awk -F" " ' { if($2~/timestamp/) { print "dateformat("$1",\047YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss\047)" } } ' datatype.txt
dateformat(b,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.sss')
>
```

Comment: @Ed, that article recommends feeding it as variable..awk -v q='"'